# Is AutoFS necessary?

Tags: solaris, autofs

In Solaris 11, if I have a single system (NAS), with no other users other than myself, can I delete autofs mappings?

To me it seems confusing to have things in two separate folders (/export/home & /home). But what I really want to know if it will break anything important.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not necessary. It's a throwback from the old Sun days when their motto was "The Network Is The Computer" - and thought that everyone would use NIS (or NIS+) and NFS home directories.

If you're not using these then autofs can safely be turned off and /home returned to your control.

Although disabling the service with `svcadm` should be enough, you might also want to edit `/etc/auto_master` and remove the entry for `/home`, just in case.

Comment: ooops, spoke too soon. Tested disabling autofs + deleting the /home line in /etc/auto_master, but now I get these errors: `could not update ICEauthority file /home/{user}/.ICEauthority`
`There is a problem with the configuration server. (user/lib/gconf-sanity-check-2 exited with status 256)`

Comment: Did you move (or symlink) the user home directories from /export/home to /home? :-)